# Time shift columns in Pandas based on Date and Hour columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data in this format:

| ID | Date | Hour | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 3 | 300 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 4 | 400 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 5 | 500 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 6 | 600 |

And I want to shift the column by n hours forward and n hours backward based on whatever next hour is present in the 'Hour' column and create dataframe like this (assuming n=1 in this case) -

| ID | Date | Hour | A | A t+1 | A t-1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | 100 | 200 | 0 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2 | 200 | 300 | 100 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 3 | 300 | 400 | 200 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 4 | 400 | 500 | 300 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 5 | 500 | 600 | 400 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 6 | 600 | 700 | 500 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 | 7 | 700 | 0 | 600 |

The date column is in datetime64 format and hour is in int64 format. I am new to Python, so please help. This is not exactly a time series data so I am avoiding converting it into Time series format and then using shift or something.

Also, for example purpose there is only one column 'A' here but I have other columns as well for which I need hour shifted numbers. Also, if hour shifts into next day, it should pick value from there.

Comment: Will your `Hour` column always be in sequential order?

Comment: By sequential, you mean sorted? That will be no.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I asked about whether the times were sequential because non-sequential times rules out the use of `.shift`  to "look ahead" (or behind), so to speak.

However, this is still fairly straightforward to do with a `for` loop (iterate over the rows, look up the `A` values in the row(s) with times matching `t+1` and `t-1`). However, looping over memory-optimized structures like DataFrames and Numpy arrays is generally frowned upon, so we will use `np.vectorize` to create a function that does the same thing but operates on the entire column at once.

For this answer, I'll assume your DataFrame is stored in a variable called `data`. Let's define a *scalar* function called `column_at_Hour` that takes in a single `hour` value and a column name and returns the value of the specified column in the row whose `"Hour"` column matches the input:

```py
def column_at_Hour(hour, column):
    try:
        return data.loc[data["Hour"]==hour, column].item()
    except ValueError: # means the specified hour was not found
        return 0 # or handle this case however you want
```

It can be used like so:

```py
In:  column_at_Hour(3, "A")

Out: 300
```

However, because we used a `==` comparison in the function, we can't pass multiple values for the `hour` argument and expect it to work. To get around this, we can wrap the function in a `np.vectorize` object, which will allow us to call it in a similar way, but with `hour` as an array of values (i.e., the entire `Hour` column). We'll create a new "function" called `column_at_Hours` that does this:

```py
column_at_Hours = np.vectorize(column_at_Hour, # original function to vectorize
                               signature="(),()->()", # original func takes two individual arguments and returns one
                               excluded="column") # column argument doesn't need to be vectorized; it will be a single value per call
```

Using it to create the `t+1` and `t-1` columns would look like this:

```py
In:  data["A(t+1)"] = column_at_Hours(data["Hour"]+1, "A") # hour advanced by 1, column A
     data["A(t-1)"] = column_at_Hours(data["Hour"]-1, "A") # hour decremented by 1, column A
     print(data)

Out:     ID        Date  Hour    A  A(t+1)  A(t-1)
      0   2  2022-01-01     1  100     200       0
      1   2  2022-01-01     2  200     300     100
      2   2  2022-01-01     3  300     400     200
      3   2  2022-01-01     4  400     500     300
      4   2  2022-01-01     5  500     600     400
      5   2  2022-01-01     6  600       0     500
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed response! How are you handling date in this? We would need to incorporate date as well while shifting the values by hour since there are multiple dates in the dataset, isn't it? Also, this logic is giving me T+1 and T-1 columns as 0 for all rows.